# Oracle: Begin statement in stored procedure not expected?

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle, so bear with me on this - I'll do as best I can.

I'm writing a stored procedure. After the `AS` statement completes, I have the following code:

```
BEGIN
IF v_Node = NULL
    BEGIN
      SET v_Node = LEFT(v_Tag, INSTR('.', v_Tag)-1)
      SET v_Node = (SELECT v_NodeId FROM DBO.nodes WHERE Node = v_Node)
    END
```

which we I compile spits out the following error:

`Error(23,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:     * & - + / at mod remainder rem then <an exponent (**)> and or    || multiset`

Can anyone help with this? 
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <<procedure name>>( <<parameter list>> )
AS
  <<variable declarations>>
BEGIN
  IF v_Node IS NULL
  THEN
    v_Node := substr( v_tag, 1, instr( '.', v_tag ) - 1 );
    SELECT v_NodeId -- Is v_NodeID really a column in dbo.nodes?  The naming 
                    -- convention would imply that it is a local variable in 
                    -- which case the SELECT statement doesn't make a lot of 
                    -- sense.
      INTO v_node
      FROM dbo.nodes
     WHERE node = v_node;
  END IF;

  <<more code>>
END;
```

The explanation

1. No value is ever equal to `NULL`, not even another `NULL`.  You need to use the `IS NULL` operator.
2. Oracle does not have a `LEFT` function.  You probably want `SUBSTR`.
3. `SET` is not a valid PL/SQL operator.  You can use the `:=` operator to assign the result of an expression to a variable.  And you can use `SELECT ... INTO` to assign the result of a SQL query to a local variable.

The remaining issues

1. It seems odd that you appear to be using the same local variable `v_Node` both to assign the `Node` string you want to search for and to hold the presumably numeric `v_NodeId` that you select from the table.  If that is really your intention, you would want separate variables.
2. The `SELECT` statement that you wrote doesn't make sense.  If `v_NodeId` is a local variable, as the naming convention implies, it doesn't make sense to select it from the `dbo.nodes` table.  It would seem more likely that you want to select the `NodeId` (assuming that is a column in `dbo.nodes`).